PAC-learning description of (quantum) hypothesis class containing randomness
I was wondering how to correctly describe the following hypothesis class mathematically correctly:
Say I have a quantum circuit which I postprocess by feeding its results into a neural network. How would the resulting description of the hypothesis class look like?
The issue I see is how to accurately describe the randomness, e.g.
the hypothesis class consists of functions $h(x) = A_k \sigma_k(A_{k-1}\sigma_{k-1}(...A_1\sigma_1(\text{meas}[\rho(x)])))$, where I don't quite know how to characterize the measurement, where $A_j$ some matrices and $\sigma$ some activation functions. Inserting the mathematical description of a measurement $h(x) = A_k \sigma_k(A_{k-1}\sigma_{k-1}(...A_1\sigma_1(\text{tr}[M*\rho(x)])))$ for example does not correctly reflect what the architecture does, since $\text{tr}[M*\rho(x)]$ is just a probability not the (random) measurement outcome. How would one describe this?
Additionally, this issue is not limited to quantum circuits but also to classes where there is randomness build in say a neural network that has a fully connected layer $A_1$ for a probability $p$ and does nothing for probability $1-p$. How would one describe these kind of hypothesis classes? It somehow needs to contain both
$h_1(x) = A_k \sigma_k( A_{k-1}\sigma_{k-1}(...\sigma_2 (A_1*x )))$
and
$h_2(x) = A_k \sigma_k( A_{k-1}\sigma_{k-1}(...\sigma_2 (x) ))$
